# Return existing primary key ID upon constraint failure in sqlite3

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, unique-constraint

I have `UNIQUE` constraint on two columns of a table in SQLite.

If I insert a record with a duplicate on these two columns into the table, I will get an exception (`sqlite3.IntegrityError`).

Is it possible to retrieve the primary key ID of this record upon such a violation, without doing an additional `SELECT`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the primary key is part of the UNIQUE constraint that led to the violation, you already have its value.

Otherwise, the two columns in the UNIQUE constraint are an alternate key for the table, i.e., they can uniquely identify the conflicting row.

If you need the actual primary key, you need to do an additional SELECT.
(The primary key of the existing row is not part of the exception because it was never looked at during the INSERT attempt.)

Comment: Yep, neither of the two columns is the primary key. And the additional SELECT is inevitable.

Answer (score 2):

You can catch the error and print it using try except

```
try:
  c.execute('''INSERT INTO spys(name) VALUES (?)''', ('Chuck',))
except sqlite3.IntegrityError as e:
  print('sqlite error: ', e.args[0])
```

Hope this helped.

Comment: thanks for the input, but how does this get me the primary key ID of the row/record that throws the error?

Comment: This kind of has a work around. I suppose it will work, though I didnt have time to test it. http://code.activestate.com/lists/python-tutor/99232/